# How to stop a nose bleed once it starts?

Tags: personal-care

If I am out somewhere and I have a nose bleed, how can I stop it in a fast and clean way?

Comment: You need to enhance this very good question by stating what you already tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: @RedSonja what do you mean?

Comment: This is something you can learn on every first aid course, and an online search would have provided a few answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I used to suffer from nose bleeds A LOT! Every time I would get one I would follow these steps: First, lean forward with firm pressure at the **top of the nose** . Once the first rush has come out, lean **back**. This will help prevent the flow of blood outwards, but redirect it inwards. This method usually helped me every time.

Additionally, if you are getting nose bleeds regularly, you might want to visit a GP to check if you don't have a damaged vein in your nose that is the cause for your nose bleed.

Answer (score 1):

I was suffering of this a lot, so I am expert on this :-)

1. Sit down, stay calm, bend your head slightly forward, use a tissue and press the nostril gently. Breathe well with the other nostril.
2. If you are overheated, e.g. the bleeding happened in hot weather or sport situation, it's very good to put wet fabric at the back of your head and at the forehead.
3. After several minutes, when you feel your blood coagulated, release the pressure and if there is no more bleeding, just breathe through the nostril (while still sitting still) - the access of oxygen will speed up the coagulation and finalize it.
4. At this point, you will probably have a mucus mixed with blood in your nose, which is not really pleasant and the coagulation might not be finished because of it ... the safest way would be to just let it be, but for me, I sometimes do a risky thing: I blow my nose... if I do it too soon, I start bleeding again; if it works, I get rid of the bloody mucus and coagulation finishes greatly and I can breathe cleanly. Most people do not recommend it though :-)

The following advices did not work for me (I got so many wrong advices from adults when I was a kid and none of them actually worked):

- bending head backward
- pressing the root of the nose

Answer (score 0):

The way we were taught to stop a nosebleed was to apply firm pressure on the upper-lip just under the nose. Lean forward, breathe through your mouth and if possible use a cold compress (ice in a cloth) to reduce swelling. That was a thousand years ago.

Edit:

Nowadays, according to Harvard.edu, however:

> Pinch with enough pressure to press both sides of your nose firmly against the septum—the cartilage in the middle of your nose. The tissue on either side of the nose puts pressure on the bleeding blood vessel, which is usually on the septum. If the bleeding slows or stops, you are pinching in the right place.

[image: Stopping Nosebleed image, NYT]

Answer (score 0):

Keep the pressure steady for 10 minutes. Not cheating to see if the bleeding has stopped. Also holding ice in your mouth may decrease the bleeding by 25%.

Comment: Gretchen, welcome! I know you can’t comment yet, but I think you wanted to chime in on another answer? Because this post doesn’t work as standalone answer (which every answer should be). The [tour] and [help], especially [answer] will explain more and you can always [edit] your post to a full answer (which then should be different from the existing ones.